# Is Air India strict with checked in baggage dimensions for international flights?

Tags: indian-citizens, international-travel, airlines, united-airlines, air-india

For economy class passengers it is mentioned that 2 checked in bags are allowed but their combined dimensions must not exceed 107 inches. How strict is Air India with this rule? Can I bring two checked in bags of 62 inch each (62 inch + 62 inch = 124 inches)?

[image]

Comment: Can you point to the page where you saw those limits? “Combined dimensions” usually means length + width + height and is usually measured per bag. Can you also specify the flight (origin and destination cities or countries), as Air India rules vary a lot depending on that?

Comment: @jcaron I believe OP is referring to [Air India](https://www.airindia.in/checked-baggage-allowances.htm) website.

Comment: @jcaron I have added the screenshot of the paragraph where Air India has mentioned the above details. For more info you may visit this link: https://www.airindia.in/checked-baggage-allowances.htm